# LaTeX Template for Drawing Chess Rules in Iconic Manner?

Tags: pdftex, chessboard

Chess game is very old. The rules are difficult for a beginner. 
Iconic overview of chess rules is a great advantage for beginners.
Would you know a cool template to  print rules with tikz ?

There is so far no example of first work.
anyhow first attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
\newgame
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

Ideally, would be to have the TIKZ source for making separate pieces queen, king,... without chessboard package.

herewith a nice rule overview. It is easy to understand since there are pics of **pieces + arrows**.  Schematics are awesome for everyone.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chessfss` package provides the useful possibility to access the chess pieces by their name, which you can use to draw the rules in tikz. One example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LSBC5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\setboardfontencoding{LSBC5}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (-1,0) {\WhiteRookOnWhite}; 
    \draw[<->] (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5);
    \fill[white] (-0.2,-0.2) rectangle (0.2,0.2);
    \node at (0,0) {\footnotesize R};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, it is amazing ! I am really impressed! thank you. However, I cannot compile it under  DEBIAN with TeXlive. I installed it a sane way, without 4GB installation. You can do also remove chesspcc and use directly my generated XFIG file: https://pastebin.com/raw/kKgYN9ny

Comment: You are not saying what error you get, so it is not possible to help you with your compilation problems but you can always replace the `\WhiteRookOnWhite` by some `\includegraphics{myrook}`.

Comment: Sounds good to me, thank you. I am trying to create TIKZ for each pieces of the chess board. But it takes me a lot of time.

Comment: @user98734 Installing `chessfss` would certainly be faster than manually creating every piece in tikz ...

Comment: Why do you want to create pictures?

Comment: Because chessfss is not installed on the current machine from the university.  I have no choice. Texlive is available still, but not all sty packages.

Comment: Then install the needed files in your local texmf. Or even in your document folder. Easier than recreate and use everything  as pictures.